# Custom style mixin for deep selectors

Tags: css, polymer-1.0, styling, web-component

I've just hit a wall with `custom-style`. Unfortunately it seems that any mixins and variables are applied to descendants of elements matched in the Light DOM. On the other hand the `:root` selector applies the vars and mixins to all custom elements.

Isn't there a middle ground where it would be possible to style eg. any custom element that has a given class etc? For example I would like to have

```
<style is="custom-style">

   my-element.important {
      --border-color: red;
   }  

</style>
```

To set the variable for each instance of `<my-element>` withe the given class. Currently it only works for elements in the Light DOM (for document level style) and Local DOM (when setting variables/mixins inside other element). It also doesn't work for anything like `:root my-element` or `:root /deep/ my-element` or `html /deep/ my-element`

I've prepared a reproduction on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1rsUXZ?p=preview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, as pointed out by [@lozandier](https://polymer.slack.com/team/lozandier) and [Karl](https://polymer.slack.com/team/ktiedt) on [Polymer's Slack channel](https://polymer.slack.com/).

For document-level styles the property groups must be wrapped in with `:root` selector

```
<style is="custom-style">

   :root {
      my-element.important {
         --border-color: red;
      }
   }  

</style>
```

And for style inside element it's necessary to use `:host` instead

```
<dom-module>
   <template>
      <style>

         :host {
            my-element.important {
               --border-color: red;
            }
         }  

       </style>
   </dom-module>
</template>
```